# How to change css class after 60 seconds in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a dynamically generated table with below format in react JS:

```
<table>
<tr className="Green"> // This class will be assigned at sometime say 10 AM
<td>Row 1</td>
<td>Row 2</td>
</tr>

<tr className="Green"> // this class will be assigned at another time say 10:01 AM
<td>Row 1</td>
<td>Row 2</td>
</tr>

<tr className="Green"> // this class will be assigned at other time say 10:02 AM
<td>Row 1</td>
<td>Row 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now my question is I want to remove the class "Green" after 60 seconds after assigning. Means the first class will be removed at 10:01 AM while others will be removed at 10:02 AM and 10:03 AM respectively.

the class "Green" is unpredictable. It will be randomly assigned to

At the same time there can be multiple  having class "Green"

How can I achieve this ? There will be no fixed no of  as those all are dynamically generated. Pardon me for poor English.

Comment: I have submitted a working answer using a proper way in React, please have a look at it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the proper way to update the `className` in React.

First, you can store all the `className` values in an array (for example `['green', 'green']`) then put the variable in a state variable (for example `isColored`.

Then, update every `className` using `setTimeout` inside a `useEffect` hook. Create one `setTimeout` for one `className` inside a `for` loop.

To simplify the return component, you can use `map` function to the state variable (`isColored`).

Here is the demo https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-curie-sm34k?file=/src/App.js.

Here is the code.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import './styles.css'

export default function App() {
  const [ isColored, setIsColored ] = useState(['green', 'green'])

  useEffect(() => {
    let timer = []
    for(let i = 0; i < isColored.length; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        timer[i] = setIsColored(previousValue => {
          let newValue = [...previousValue]
          // update the value of className here for example 'blue'
          // use '' to remove the className
          newValue[i] = ''
          return newValue
        })
      }, 60000 * (i + 1))
    }
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {isColored.map((item, index) => (
        <div 
          key={index}
          className={item}
        >
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this'll work.

```
const remove = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('green')

    if (elements.length > 0) {
      elements[elements.length - 1].classList.remove('green')

      if (elements.length !== 1) {
        remove()
      }
    }
  }, 60000)
}
```

Or something like that, you can change that up a bit depending on what you want to do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated as per comments.**

You are dynamically applying your `green` class and want to highlight your table row for a minute. You can do this directly by CSS:

```css
.green {
  animation: highlight 60s;
}

@keyframes highlight {
  from,
  99% {
    color: green;
  }
  to {
    color: initial;
  }
}
```

And, then if you want to truly remove the class, you can listen for the [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) event on your table. And remove the `green` class then:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const classRemover = (event) => {
      event.target.classList.remove('green');
    };

    const tableToWatch = document.querySelector('#watch-this-table');
    tableToWatch.addEventListener('animationend', classRemover);

    return () => {
      tableToWatch.removeEventListener('animationend', classRemover);
    };
  }, []);
```

---

**Ignore the content below.**

If your structure is same as the one you posted in the question, then you can directly use [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) along with the [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) method like this:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const IndexPage = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      try {
        const current = document.querySelector('.green.active');
        current.classList.remove('active');
        current.nextSibling.classList.add('active');
      } catch {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 60 * 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr className="green active">
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
          </tr>

          <tr className="green">
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
          </tr>

          <tr className="green">
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <style jsx global>{`
        .green.active {
          color: green;
        }
      `}</style>
    </>
  );
};

export default IndexPage;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. but the class "Green" is unpredictable. It will be randomly assigned to <tr>

Comment: @HarenSarma What do you mean by randomly assigned? Can you explain more what is the use case? How exactly are you applying class to your `<tr>`?

Comment: I am using a math, if the value of a data is greater than the previous one, the <tr> will be Green Background for 60 seconds. there can be 2-3 datas at the same time higher than the previous ones. Then all those <tr> will be green for 60 seconds.

Comment: Basically you want to change remove the green class after 60s of its application, irrespective of other table rows? Sort of highlighting it for a minute?

Comment: @HarenSarma I've updated my answer, give it a look once.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an idea. Create two functions similar to these:

```
let displayGreen = true

function resolveAfter60Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 60000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  const result = await resolveAfter60Seconds();
  displayGreen = false
  console.log(result);
  // expected output: "resolved"
}

asyncCall();
```

It is my belief that this will wait 60 seconds to run, and after this happens, a variable such as `displayGreen` will be equal to false. You can render the green div only if that variable is true (conditional rendering).
Hope this works!

Comment: it would be great if you told how it works